# Is there a performance difference between append SVG elements to Document Fragment and SVG GROUP

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, documentfragment

I read that it is sometimes a good idea to append DOM elements to a Document Fragment first in order to avoid reflow (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).

Working with SVG I am wondering whether there is a (performance) difference between appending all SVG elements before appending to the DOM tree to

1. a Document Fragment
2. a SVG group element (not yet appended to the DOM tree)

Maybe someone has a clue.

Comment: My guess is that the question is answered by the more general question about appending to Document Fragment vs. parent element (not yet appended).

Comment: SVG elements don't reflow. The article is talking about html elements.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds sensible. So reflow is no worry. I guess one worry left might be (non-reflow) recalculations from the rendering of SVG elements. But my guess in that case a not yet appended group is as good as it gets.